# Create Multiple Loop Page

Tags: wordpress

hi i want to create a multiple loop page for archive / category / tag

i am very confused, plz help

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();          
if($count == 1) : ?>
```

<-- First loop --> I need only 1 post in this loop (so i add above code)

```
 <?php else : ?>
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '44'); ?>
```

<-- second loop -->  (1 post in this loop)

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '35'); ?>
```

<-- Third loop -->  (4 post in this loop)

```
  <ul><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li></ul>
```

<-- Fourth loop -->  (Rest of all posts will be in this loop)

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'cover')); ?>
 <div class=""></div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '44'); ?></div>

 <?php endif; ?>    
 <?php $count++; ?> 
 <?php endwhile; ?> 
 </div><!-- /.post -->
 <?php else : ?>

 <h2 class="archiveTitle"><?php _e('Sorry, nothing matched your criteria','linepress');?></h2> 
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop that has a section on using multiple loops.  that has always worked for me.

Comment: Not exactly sure how to help then.

Comment: please have a look what i want to say http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798632/how-to-split-loop-in-multiple-column-in-archive-page